# VB Excel - When opening a word doc from VB with Excel I get a 'Variable not defined' error when trying to use ActiveDocument

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have a a requirement to open a Word doc from Excel and substitute text in a Text Box in the Word doc with text from the Excel spreadsheet.

I recorded a Macro with Word and it said to use `ActiveDocument`, however when I try to use this in my code within Excel, I get a `Variable not defined error`.

Here is my code -

```
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\kmccorma\Desktop\ReportPage.doc"

ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 12").Select
```

I tried objWord.Shapes but I get an error saying Object doesnt support this property.

I can see the Shapes property is available with `ActiveChart`, do I need to do something with `ActiveChart` to get this to work?

Still relatively new to VB, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I have just found that I didnt have the Microsoft Word Library selected, issue resolved.

Comment: That is only when you are early binding else when you are late binding then you will have to use the code that I gave below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, Excel doesn't recognize what `ActiveDocument` is. I would recommend using Objects. See this example.

```
Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\kmccorma\Desktop\ReportPage.doc")

With objDoc.Shapes("Text Box 12")
    '~~> Do Something
    '.Select
End With
```